# Why my external DB is not accessible in Android 4?

Tags: android

```
   @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, CursorFactory factory){
         File externalFilesDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         if(externalFilesDir == null) 
                return null;
         File dbFile = new File(externalFilesDir, SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
         return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }
```

I use the above code to write my db file into the external storage. So it is saved at `/mnt/sdcard/`. When i try it in Android 2.3.5 it works. But with Android 4 it do not work. But still it do not give me any errors.

Comment: have you used the write_external_storage permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes. This works fine in Android 2.3.5, But not in 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for some one else whos looking for the same thing.

```
 // ======= This will allow to create the DB in /mnt/sdcard/
    // External folder DB access for Android 4+
       @Override
       public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode,CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
             File externalFilesDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             if(externalFilesDir == null) 
                    return null;
             File dbFile = new File(externalFilesDir, SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
             return super.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile.getAbsolutePath(), Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null, errorHandler);
       }

       // External folder DB access for Android 2.3
    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, CursorFactory factory){
         File externalFilesDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         if(externalFilesDir == null) 
                return null;
         File dbFile = new File(externalFilesDir, SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
         return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }
```